# Reading Already Sent PHP Content

Tags: php

Is there a way to read all the text that has already been sent to the client without using `ob_start`?

Comment: Not that I know of - You'd need to buffer the output you've sent _somewhere_.

Comment: Depending on yours application design you should save the content in a variable (or such) _before_ sending it.

Comment: @afuzzyllama i was just wondering if it needed `ob_start` or there was already a buffer storing the information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Capturing the output is the exact purpose of Output Buffering.  If you could describe *why* you can't use output buffering we may be able to help you more.